# Univocity - Is it possible to parse a file to a runtime generated bean/class?

Tags: java, code-generation, javassist, univocity

I am using univocity to parse some files to javabeans. These beans are compiled classes. However I wish to generate these classes during runtime and then parse the files to the at runtime generated classes.

Full code is here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/smieras/f4e73959c132241cc93984c949ab3d14)

A snippet of the code that uses the Univocity library:

```
private static void parseBean(final Class<?> dynamicClass) throws FileNotFoundException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final BeanListProcessor<?> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Class<?>>((Class<Class<?>>) dynamicClass);

        final CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
        parserSettings.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
        parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(false);
        parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter('|');
        parserSettings.setEmptyValue("");
        parserSettings.setNullValue("");

        final CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
        parser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/person.csv"));

        final List<?> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
        for (final Object domain : beans) {
            final Domain domainImpl = (Domain) domain;
            System.out.println("Person id is: " + domainImpl.getIdentifier());
            System.out.println("Person name is: " + domainImpl.getColumnByIndex(1));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The file looks like this:

```
0|Eric
1|Maria
```

All the values seems to be null, so something is going wrong when parsing the file and mapping it to the bean...

```
Person id is: null
Person name is: null
```

**Is it possible to parse files to runtime generated beans/classes using the Univocity library?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your code is not generating the `@Parsed` annotations correctly. Check this:

```
    Object o = dynamicClass.newInstance();
    Field f = dynamicClass.getDeclaredField("id");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations = f.getAnnotations();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(annotations));
```

You will get an empty annotation array. I've fixed your code to generate the annotations properly:

Change your `addAnnotation` method to this:

```
private static void addAnnotation(final CtClass clazz, final String fieldName, final String annotationName, String member, int memberValue) throws Exception {
    final ClassFile cfile = clazz.getClassFile();
    final ConstPool cpool = cfile.getConstPool();
    final CtField cfield = clazz.getField(fieldName);

    final AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(cpool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    final Annotation annot = new Annotation(annotationName, cpool);
    annot.addMemberValue(member, new IntegerMemberValue(cpool, memberValue));
    attr.addAnnotation(annot);
    cfield.getFieldInfo().addAttribute(attr);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
addAnnotation(cc, "id", "com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Parsed","index", 0);
```

With this change, I can parse a sample input such as this:

```
parser.parse(new StringReader("0|John|12-04-1986"));
```

And will get the following output:

```
Person id is: 0
Person name is: John
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out the wrongly generated annotation code and thanks even more for the code fix.

Comment: @Sander_M - do you mind fixing the gist link/showing the original code?